Getting cors error while trying MFE using Module Federation
I try to achieve MFE using module federation.I go through this link to achieve this.
Everything was going perfectly until I ran the base/host application. It's throwing cors error while connecting to the remoteEntry.js file.
This file can be directly accessible from the URL but not from the angular app.
Getting this error in browser.
Access to script at 'http://localhost:8090/remoteEntry.js' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
main.js:1     GET http://localhost:8090/remoteEntry.js net::ERR_FAILED 200 (OK)

In my :8090 node server,cors is already there.
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type, Authorization');
    next();
});

Added to the app.js file.
Did I missed something ?
EDIT :
In angular module federation app, we are adding module federation libray using ng add @angular-architects/module-federation@16 --project remoteapplazy2 --port 5002.Now  in host app,we are adding the remote entry path like http://localhost:5002/remoteEntry.js .Now If we run the host app and remote app using ng serve it's working fine. But If we build the remote app using ng build and run the file using a node server running 8091 port we are error GET http://localhost:5002/remoteEntry.js net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED  main.ts:5 Error loading remote entries TypeError: Failed to fetch dynamically imported module: http://localhost:5002/remoteEntry.js . Now If we run the nodejs server using 5002 port ,getting cors error Access to script at 'http://localhost:5002/remoteEntry.js' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
Is this really cors error or should I miss anything to build the app and run in the server? Is there any other process to run the code in server?
I created a html for testing
<html>
    <body>Test
        <script src="http://localhost:5002/remoteEntry.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>

and run this.There is no cors error.

it's sending a preflight request and not getting a response.  Sorta strange since a GET should be a simple request... maybe custom headers are being sent?  Make sure the backend is able to respond to OPTIONS request.... (import a CORS module?)  You could alternatively use a proxy to have the front-end and back-end served from same port.  (That way you don't have to loosen your security by sending CORS headers)

I modified the cors res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST,OPTIONS'); like this. Still it's not working.

@browsermator The error message indicates that preflight is not the issue, though.

@Subham Please produce a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

@jub0bs I have edit the question with some extra comments.Also I have added the link where from where I copied the codebase.If it's not enough, I'll add some codebase.
